# How ServerSocket is able to receive HTTP requests?

Tags: java, http, port, serversocket

I have implemented simple client-server program using socket programming. Here is my server code snippet,

```
ServerSocket listner = new ServerSocket(9000);
while(true){
Socket socket = listner.accept();
// here a new thread is spawn for each request Which prints 
// the data received from client using socket input stream
}
```

When the server is up and URL(http://localhost:9000) is hit from the browser, I can see HTTP get request is printed on the console.

As far as I know HTTP listens to port 80(i.e., all incoming HTTP request comes via this port). My question is, how come http requests are received via port 9000. If the URL I'm using tells to ignore (or may be by pass) port 80? Then, how to implement server program using sockets which listens to standard HTTP port:80(I mean by htting URL http://localhost/).

Comment: The default port is 80, but a browser can use any port, and your server could listen to port 80 if you wanted. If you want to use port 80, replace 9000 with 80.

Answer (score 2):

While the **default** HTTP port is 80, nothing stops you from using another port. In fact other ports are also commonly used such as `8080` and higher numbers that do not conflict with the standard port numbers used for other applications (email etc.)

Your example worked because you are listening on port 9000, due to this line:

`ServerSocket listner = new ServerSocket(9000);`

The corresponding URL you used in your browser was: 
http://localhost:9000

So it was explicitly telling the browser to use 9000 not 80.

If you wanted to use 80, you just change the port number to 80 from that line in the `ServerSocket` constructor, assuming nothing else is already using port 80 on the same network interface.

Comment: Port 80 is privileged on most Unix systems.

Comment: @chrylis not relevant for the OP's question (this is about programming not operating systems). But you can just run your program as `sudo`. There is no difference between running `Apache`, `Nginx` or your software, both do the same thing when opening a socket.